# Recursively setting all files in a directory as non-executable

Tags: permissions, executable, ntfs

I have an external hard-drive formatted as NTFS which I use to back-up and store files from both Linux and Windows (as I am dual-booting). I recently bought a new computer and installed Linux Mint 20 on it, and I would like to copy some of the files from my back-up to my computer's internal HD. I noticed that every single file in every single subfolder I copied from the hard-drive has had the option `Allow executing file as program` enabled in its permissions. How can I safely recursively run through a directory and set all files in all subdirectories as non-executable (including hidden ones and in hidden folders starting with `.`)?

Also, is there a way of preventing this to happen in a NTFS hard-drive or would I be better off creating two partitions on it, an EXT4 for Linux and a NTFS for Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to use:

```
chmod -R -x+X .
```

See [chmod(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html)